# Why is my design compiled by Quartus II successfully but no logic utilization?

Tags: compilation, verilog, fpga

Sorry for such a general question. I have experience in Verilog but new to FPGA and Quartus II. I use Quartus II to try to compile a design and to see how much logic the design uses. I followed the quick tutorial of Quartus II by Altera. http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/mnl_qts_quick_start.pdf

However, after the step of analysis and synthesis, I noticed there is no logic utilization at all. Only the two Input pins of top module could be seen.

[image]

The top module of my design is

```
RiSC(clk,reset)
```

Naturally, after compilation, there is still nothing but two pins.

[image]

Have you ever met this problem? Could you give me some hint? The design contains hundreds of lines of verilog codes so there should be logic utilization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unused outputs will be optimized out.  You're going to have to route out some outputs otherwise the synthesizer will nuke all of the logic.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean I need to have output in my top module, or the logic utilization will be zero?

Comment: Yep.  The synthesizer is smart - it removes all logic whose outputs are unused.  And if nothing is routed out of the chip, then all of the logic can be removed without affecting the design as far as the synthesizer is concerned.

Comment: Is this true for all the synthesizers? This design is a small CPU so in my opinion it's a little bit difficult to have outputs to keep all the logic from being removed by synthesizer.

Comment: However, I think it's natural that CPU only has clock and reset as input pins.

Comment: What's the purpose of a CPU without an output? How do you know what it calculates? Do you just want to know how much area it consumes? Then an easy way is just to add/or/xor all outputs together and assign it to a single, physical pin. Also, some tools (at least Xilinx ISE) have special options to explicitly disable the output-removal on the top-level.

Comment: @mbschenkel Thanks. This is the architecture of that CPU. http://www.ece.umd.edu/class/enee646.F2011/p2.pdf It has instrucution memory and data memory. So it just reads instructions and data from memories, executes instructions and gets results to store in data memory. There is no output. So what I'm thinking is maybe I should put instruction and data memory modules outside CPU module so there will be output pins for CPU module to communicate with external instruction or data memory.

Comment: I would suggest breaking out the address and data bus pins.  You don't have to set it up like the memory would be outside of the FPGA, though.  Just a 'tap' that you could use e.g. for a logic analyzer should be sufficient to keep the synthesizer from optimizing away your entire design.

Comment: Can you add a simple perpiheral, like an 8 bit LED ort, or a simple UART?  That would provide enough output to convince the synthesiser that you want to keep all of your logic.

Comment: You can also have a look at the Altera synthesizer DS (http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii51008.pdf) and search for "preserve registers", "synthesis keep" and the corresponding attributes. Adding timing-constraints might work as well. However, this auto-removal is a feature you want to disable only in an accademic context, therefore I haven't tried that...

Comment: @alex.forencich I've tried your suggestion and it works! I add two outputs. One of them is the XOR of all the outputs of datapath in each stage; the other output is the XOR of all the PCs in each stage, which contain address.But I don't know whether any logic is removed by synthesizer. What I do is just to add possible internal nodes until no more logic increase in the synthesis summary.

Comment: @mbschenkel I tried the directives of "synthesis keep","preserve registers" and they didn't work. I found a thread on Altera forum saying these options doesn't work for this case, where the removal is caused by no output. Why do you say this could happen "only in an academic context"? Is it because CPU need to communicate with peripherals in the actual design so there must be outputs?

Comment: Because in any real design you don't need any logic if its output is unconnected. (That would be like a blind person watching a movie...) The only way it can communicate with the outside world is by generating waste-heat... So, removing it is actually a feature, e.g. you can write a generic module with multiple outputs and connect only some and still be sure that the implementation will optimize away unused data-paths. Only under special "academic" circumstances (e.g. estimating the size of an implementation that is not yet finished or connected) do you want to keep such unobservable logic.